# How to share enum between classes which are not in family?

Tags: c++, oop, class, enums

It's very simple question but I don't know the answer.

```
   class a
   {
    public:
    enum xxx {one, two}
   }

   class b
   {
    //cant inherit from a
    //what I want to do is:
    xxx object = one;
   }
```

How can I make the enum to be known in class b? Of course I can declare it in both classes but that's non-clean. As I said, I can't inherit because those two classes do completely different things and should be independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope resolution operator:

```
a::xxx object;
```

Comment: what exactly should I make static?

Comment: I can initialize it without making anything static.

Comment: @user1873947: You *should* make nothing `static`. A conformant compiler will not let you initialize `object` like that (you would have to do that with the constructor) *unless* it is `static`, but that doesn't mean you have to make it `static`. Just use the constructor.

Comment: g++ 4.7 with c++11 flag doesn't even give me a warning with such initialization. Are you sure that it should be static? What's more, I use -wall (all warnings).

Comment: i have in class b definition: "a::xxx object = a::one" and I get no warnings. Why object should be static? What's the point?

Comment: In C++11 you **can** initialize class members in the class definition. The comments to the contrary apply only to C++98/03

Comment: @JoergB: I decided to remove that line entirely since C++11 is where it's at right now. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought that c++11 allows it.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's public you should be able to access it by a fully qualified name:

```
a::xxx object;
```

Values would be used the same way `a::one`, `a::two`, etc.

EDIT: See the discussion in the comments for the other answer about whether or not you can do an inline initialization.